# Can I make a rails cucumber defenition any shorter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

I'm getting started with cucumber, and I have written the following step definition, which basically I copied from the rspec test I already had.

```
Given /^There is a picture on the screen$/ do
  describe PagesController do
    describe "GET 'home'" do
      it "should be successful" do
        get 'home'
        response.should be_success
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now I'm also quite new to Rails. But this seems a bit long to me, can't I make it any shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing there is a big antipattern when writing tests with Cucumber.  You haven't broken down your step far enough—when you look at the test you've got, you're actually going through at least a couple of different steps, one of which isn't something you want to test.  A better test for this would be:

```
Given I am on the home page
Then I should see a picture
```

The first step you get for free when you install capybara's web steps, provided you are using the default path helper in `features/support/paths.rb`.  The second one would look like this:

```
Then "I should see a picture" do 
  page.should have_selector("img.picture")
end
```

That step is going to look for an image with a 'picture' class on it—my arbitrary definition of what a picture is in the context of your application.

Notice that I'm not checking the response status here.  The idea behind cucumber (even moreso than Rspec) is that you test things from the perspective of the client.  Arguably your client may be a client API, so perhaps checking the status code is appropriate, but in general with a web app, you're much more concerned about the UI, and a failing status code will manifest itself in other ways, such as a broken UI.  Details like status codes are generally implementation details that shouldn't be tested from a BDD point of view (though they *should* be covered in your unit tests.)

FWIW, I also disagree with the assertion that the length of the test is what should determine whether you should be using Rspec or Cucumber.  See my blog post on the matter: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/04/15/language-matters/

Comment: Thanks, I will go have a play with this. I never ment to say that the length of tests should have any influence on any choice, just that because it was quite long, doing so little, I feared that I'd done something wrong, which clearly I did.

Comment: I was referring to the previous answer with that bit about test length. :)

Comment: Your answer is very helpful yet I keep running into errors that don't seem logic to me, and don't fit your example. I have not changed the generated home.html.erb page, so it should contain a p tag. It does when I check the source in my browser or check the file, but using the code you provided, giving page.shoud have_selector("p") remains red... Did I mis something?

Comment: Is "home" a reserved term or something?

Comment: if you look in paths.rb, you'll see a default implementation that's basically a big case statement—it presumes "home page" is going to point to the root path and returns '/', which you can change if you want, though I don't recommend it.  spend a little time looking at the implementation of the default branch of that case statement and see if you can figure out how it saves you effort if you stick to calling your pages by their route helpers (e.g. "the edit blog page"...)

Comment: also a debugging tip, if you add launchy to your gems you can use a step "Then show me the page" anywhere in a cuke and it'll open the current page in a browser for you to look at. In your case I'd make sure you're actually loading the page you want. You're probably going to your root path, per my comment above, when you're expecting to be on /home.

Comment: One important addition: I have struggled with what path to give to "Given I am on the ... page". I wanted to give Pages#home. To do so, use: "Given I am on the pages home page". And when I created the path "server/test" pointing at the view, "Given I am on the server test page" will point to the view too. For anyone passing by;)

Comment: And my special thanks to Karmajunkie, who saved my day today^^

Answer (score 1):

It would strongly recommend not using Cucumber until you're more familiar with Rails/Ruby. Cucumber adds a level of abstraction that can make things very confusing, frustrating and time consuming. Just get very good with RSpec first. Then when you want to do integration tests on your Rails app, use Capybara with RSpec. When you're comfortable using those gems, you can go to Cucumber.

Cucumber is about writing user stories. You then translate those Cucumber steps into lines of RSpec and Capybara.

Comment: Thanks, but you probably guessed already that I'm going to be stubborn here. I know what the goal of Cucumber is, and I want to see how far I get with it. Failure is an option, I can always drop it and stick to RSpec and Capybara if using Cucumber starts to consume too much time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for brevity, I would recommend sticking to RSpec. Cucumber's main advantage is its readability to people who do not write code, while RSpec sacrifices that in order to be shorter. I tried to use [Lettuce](http://lettuce.it), a python analogue to Cucumber, on one of my projects and found it to be way too much work to keep up.

So, in short: if you want to write shorter tests, use RSpec. If you want your developer to edit your tests or you are working in a team, use Cucumber.

Comment: It's not that I need short tests or something, just that I was afraid I was doing something wrong, because it looks so long.

Comment: it's pretty verbose, yeah. But that *is* the correct way to do it.

Comment: Whaha, no it seems not, I can't get this test to go red. Can you tell me what the correct way is, karmajunkie?

Comment: I switched to Webrat instead of rspec for the step defenitions, which allows the content of the step to be:
  visit '/pages/home'
  response.should contain("Something not there")
this one does go red. So if anyone comes by with the same problem switching to webrat would help. But I'm still curious how to use rspec in this context.